# Why can't I get passthrough subjects to work for combine?

Tags: ios, swift, combine

Just getting into `Combine`, and for some reason I can't get `passthrough subjects` to work. Even though I have copy-pasted examples from multiple different sources, they just won't print anything. I have tried with `Publishers` and `CurrentValueSubjects` and they work fine, but with `PassThroughSubjects`; nope. Here's an example that I have tried:

```
let mySubject = PassthroughSubject<String, Error>()

mySubject.sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
        print("-- completion", completion)
    }, receiveValue: { value in
        print("-- value", value)
}).cancel()

mySubject.send("one")
mySubject.send("two")
mySubject.send("three")
```

This is run in `viewDidLoad`.
What am I doing wrong?

Like I said, I have tried `Publishers` and `CurrentValueSubjects` with success:

```
["one", "two", "three"].publisher
    .sink(receiveValue: { v in
        print("-- hello", v)
}).cancel()

let subject = CurrentValueSubject<String, Error>("Initial Value")

subject.send("Hello")

subject.sink(receiveCompletion: { c in
    print("-- completion", c)
}, receiveValue: { v in
    print("-- value", v)
}).cancel()
```

Comment: You `cancel`ed before you sent the values. Try moving the `send` calls to the end.

Comment: Coming from rx I imagined .cancel() worked like .dispose(by:), but you're saying that I cancel the subscription immediately when hooking on .cancel? If I remove .cancel() I get a warning that the subscription is unused. Instead at the end I try adding  mySubject.cancel() but get an error. The only way I get it to work is to store the entire subscription in yet another variable and then adding .cancel() at the bottom... very very strange... explanation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The warning that you are seeing that the subscription is unused is a hint to store the token returned by `sink` like so:

```
let mySubject = PassthroughSubject<String, Error>()

let cancellable = mySubject
    .sink(
        receiveCompletion: { completion in
            print("-- completion", completion)
        },
        receiveValue: { value in
            print("-- value", value)
        }
    )
```

then when you call:

```
mySubject.send("one")
mySubject.send("two")
mySubject.send("three")
```

you will see this printed out:

```
-- value one
-- value two
-- value three
```

you can cancel the subscription if you are not longer interested in receiving updates:

```
cancellable.cancel()
```

or you can send a completion:

```
mySubject.send(completion: .finished)
```

and then you will see this printed out:

```
-- completion finished
```

Answer (score 4):

> Coming from rx I imagined `.cancel()` worked like `.dispose(by:)`

No, `cancel()` is like `dispose()`, *not* `disposed(by:)` in rx. You should not `cancel` first, then `send` things to the subject. And unlike a `CurrentValueSubject`, it doesn't remember the value you sent it, so you must send values to it after you `sink`, but before you `cancel`.

Just like how you would use a `DisposeBag` in rx, you should do this with a `Set<AnyCancellable>` in Combine:

```
var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
```

The Combine counterpart of `disposed(by:)` is [`store(in:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/anycancellable/store(in:)-3hyxs):

```
subject.sink(receiveCompletion: { c in
    print("-- completion", c)
}, receiveValue: { v in
    print("-- value", v)
}).store(in: &cancellables)

subject.send("Hello")
```